# how to return node as property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

i'm trying to get my data in one result object that facebookPage is a property of campaign my query :

```
MATCH (campaign:Campaign {id:'62'}) with campaign 
MATCH (facebookPage:FacebookPage {id:'3009799'}) with
{campaign:campaign,facebookPage:facebookPage} as campaign  
RETURN campaign
```

in this query im getting the result in one object but not as campaign one of campaign property

Comment: You cannot add a node as virtual property to another node. What you do is correct, except you don't need any of your `WITH` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal statement you would use:

```
MATCH (campaign:Campaign {id:'62'}) 
MATCH (facebookPage:FacebookPage {id:'3009799'}) 
RETURN {campaign:campaign,facebookPage:facebookPage} as campaign
```

Comment: its work but its not what I meant i'm getting : 
campaign {
                   {id:1234}
                   {name:"test"}
facebookPage {
                            ....
and i want :
campaign {
                   {id:1234}
                   {name:"test"}
                   {facebookPage} {
                                                .....